# Need to compare a given face input image across an already stored labelled collection using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

I have a collection of profile images from customers I need to be able to pass a selfie of the person and scan it across the collection of images and pull up the customer information.

Need to do the following using AWS Rekognition -

- Create a collection - Done
- Add Images to the collection - Whats the REST API syntax for this
- While adding the images to the collection also tag it with the customer name.
- Take a selfie portrait and search across the collection and return the tag information which matches.

Im using Flutter as a platform hence there is no support for AWS SDK so will need to make REST API calls.
However the AWS docs don't provide much information for REST support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APIs are documented. For example to detect faces in an image and add them to a collection, see [IndexFaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_IndexFaces.html).

I'd personally recommend getting comfortable with Rekognition via the awscli (or Python/boto3) briefly before you move to the Rest API.

On the name tagging front, you assign an 'external ID' to faces when adding them to a collection. That external ID is the correlator that you supply and that Rekognition stores. Later, when you ask Rekognition if a given face matches one already in a collection, Rekognition will return you the external ID. That can then be used as a lookup into some database that you have to identify the person's name, date of birth, or whatever.